# Window Phone is there an equivalent to iOS Core Text

Tags: windows-phone-7, text, core-text

We have an App for iOS that renders much text: http://bit.ly/IekVmU

We use CoreText in iOS to render the pre-formatted text and allow the user to change formatting, font-size and font face.

We are trying to port it to Windows Phone but I'm not sure if there's a substitute for CoreText in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP7 allows you to create text from Runs, for example:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold">I am Bold</Run>
        <Run>I am not</Run>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

This allows you to create blocks of text with mixed format.

Comment: Is there an easy way to paginate?

Comment: nope and the maximal height on Windows Phone is 2048 pixels so beware of long texts ... You got also the RichTextBlock control.